# What is the time and space complexity of a standard SOM algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory, data-mining, self-organizing-maps

I am trying to understand the time complexity of a standard SOM algorithm. 
Given D dimensional Input, a total of N inputs, over a set of E epochs and for an M*M sized map, what would be the complexity?

I am confused about the discussion https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/147313/what-is-the-computational-complexity-of-the-som-algorithm.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are confused about the answer you linked to, why not post a comment on it asking for clarification?

Comment: It discusses the complexity in the context of text classification. I want to understand the complexity of a vanilla SOM. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason to suppose the time complexity should be different when the algorithm is applied to a problem in a different domain? Or is there a reason to suppose that that question, which is about *"the SOM algorithm"* / *"the classic SOM algorithm"* is asking about a different algorithm to the one you intend to ask about? I certainly don't see enough detail in your question to distinguish it from the one you linked to, and the reference to text classification only appears in the paper that that answer cites, not in the answer itself.

Comment: The linked discussion doesn't take into account the grid/map size. I am unable to interpret the solution. Could you please help me explaining the complexity of the classic SOM?